How to remove some of the default filters of Kendo-react-grid for react
I am using kendo-react-grid into my react project version 7.2.3. I need to enable filtering on columns, but at the same time i need to exclude some of them because I don't really need them. For example i don't need is null and is not null as they are too specific and the clients don't understand the meaning of those filters. Is there a way to do it?
Possibly I would like to do it directly on the Grid and not on every column since adding custom filters might result too complex in my case.
I found this, but I don't understand where to put that settings. It is also a very old version and for jquery. Do you have any suggestion for recent versions and for react grid?

I found out here we can set the grid filter operators and pass them to the grid.
Example:
<Grid
  data={data}
  //...
  filterOperators={gridFilterOperators}
>
//...
</Grid>

where gridFilterOperators is an object with the values described in the link above.
const gridFilterOperators = {
  text: [{ text: 'grid.filterEqOperator', operator: 'eq' }],
  numeric: [{ text: 'grid.filterEqOperator', operator: 'eq' }],
  date: [{ text: 'grid.filterEqOperator', operator: 'eq' }],
  boolean: [{ text: 'grid.filterEqOperator', operator: 'eq' }]
}

In this example all the default filters will have only the equals filter.
